# Draw on canvas html5 using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, text, canvas, drawing

I'm using JQuery to draw on a canvas

I want to create a groundplan with rooms, in these rooms the name of the room need to be displayed but the problem with this is that the text isn't readable

The html code of my canvas is:

My Jquery to fill this canvas looks like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("groundplan"); 
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    function drawRoom(p1, p2, length, breath, color){
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(p1,p2,length,breath);
    context.fillStyle = color
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 0.2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.stroke();
    }
//class room
drawRoom(0,0,50,75, '#7ca0ad');
drawRoom(50,0,50,75, '#7ca0ad');
drawRoom(100,0,50,75, '#7ca0ad');
drawRoom(150,0,100,75, '#7ca0ad');
drawRoom(250,0,50,100, '#7ca0ad');
//teacher room
drawRoom(250,100,50,50, '#91a0a5');
//cafetaria
drawRoom(50,100,175,100, '#74bbd3');
//wc
drawRoom(0,100,50,75, '#91a0a5');
    function drawLabel(text, p1, p2){
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fillText(text, p1, p2);
    }
drawLabel("GR200", 30,30);
```

Comment: canvas is specified like this in html:

<section>
  <canvas id="groundplan"/>
 </section>

Answer (score 0):

Changing the style of the font used is easy enough:

```
context.font = '2em _sans bold';
```

take a look here for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_font.asp

Comment: I know, but it just doesn't look great.. The quality is bad

image:
http://nl.tinypic.com/r/mjxrua/5

Comment: The text in that image looks like it has been scaled up; are you performing a trasnform to the drawing context before you add the text? Text in canvas is [rasterized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) so doesn't scale nicely in the way that traditional HTML text does